# how can i create a short cut for auto-format tags on document in sublime plugin 'tag'?

Tags: html, sublimetext3, auto-indent

I want to create a short cut for 'Auto-Format Tags on Document' in Sublime plugin 'Tag' and it works when i choose this function from   **Edit -> Tag -> Auto-Format Tags on Document**.

However i add this code in keybindings

```
 { "keys": [ "command+alt+s" ], "command": "Auto-Format Tags on Document" }
```

It didn't work and this combination shortcut keys is available.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mac you need to refer about <kbd>⌘</kbd> key as <kbd>super</kbd> in your keybinding file.

And then if you look in your *Key Binding - Default file* you will see this combo is already taken :

```
{ "keys": ["super+alt+s"], "command": "save_all" },
```

You need to change this value in your *Keys Binding - User file* if you do not wants to lose this shortcut :D

All documentation is available on sublimetext website as unofficial doc : [go to keybinding documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html).

> ### Modifiers
>
> - <kbd>shift</kbd>
> - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>
> - <kbd>alt</kbd>
> - <kbd>super</kbd> (Windows key, Command key...)

Should resolve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

> **For windows user** : `{"keys": ["f7"], "command": "tag_indent_document"},`

and it's obvious you can use your own key combination instead of <kbd>f7</kbd> ;)

**[Docs available here:](https://github.com/titoBouzout/Tag)**

**Extra:** if you searching online tool to check unclose html tags

[**Check this awesome site**](http://jona.ca/blog/unclosed-tag-finder)